# After upgrade free-bsd 11.1->12.0->12.1 libraries are missing

Tags: freebsd

How can I restore these?
pkg misses a library (libarchive.so.6) so that way is closed

BTW the missing libs still show up in locate (/usr/lib)

J

Comment: It looks like you have an old version of `pkg` on your system. Does `pkg-static` work instead?

Comment: yes, it does. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

You should update all packages for the new arch.

Please run "pkg-static upgrade" and proceed.

Afterwards there should be no program left that uses outdated libraries.